# How to get path or name of image that store in Storage?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to store images in storage also that image name in database.

```
$file = $request->file('attachments');
Storage::disk('public')->put('images',$file);

$attachments = new Attachment();
$attachments->title = $title;
$attachments->path = "NAME OF IMAGE THAT ALREADY STORED ($FILE)";

$inbox_attachments->save();
```

Example of image name is

> 5MgomzwHmMxUhKqRu7T4SMhjvfrWtdKLArBSc3bI.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):**

> basename — Returns trailing name component of path

**Try this:**

```
$storagePath = Storage::disk('public')->put('images',$file);

$attachments->path = basename($storagePath);
```

Comment: Sure I will soon